# Set default radio button in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, radio-button

I wanted to set the default radio button on my Android app in Android Studio. I have my buttons set up in the XML file and I am very new to making apps. I just want to know how to set the default button when the app is opened.

I have looked on the internet but I cannot understand what to do. I want something like this: http://cloud.addictivetips.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/SoShare-Android-Share.jpg

If you post some code, can you please comment it so I know what is happening?

Comment: Get the view ID of the button and make it checked true like    radiobutton.setChecked(true);

Comment: how? i am new to this

Comment: Paste your code which is related to the radio button.

Comment: i dont have any code. i just did the android:checked=true in the xml but then the java code related to the button doesn't work. for the code it is still unchecked

Comment: you can do this by adding below line in RadioGroup view, android:checkedButton="id of RadioButton"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put like this..

Using Xml.

```
                         <RadioGroup
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">
                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="RadioButton1"
                                android:checked="true"
                                android:id="@+id/radio1"
                                />
                            <RadioButton
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="RadioButton2"
                                android:id="@+id/radio2"
                                />
                        </RadioGroup>
```

Using Java:

```
   RadioGroup radiogroup;

       radiogroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)

       radiogroup.check(R.id.radio1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Say if you have this xml consist of radio buttons like below

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
</RadioGroup>
```

You can simply write below code:

```
radiobutton1 =(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radiobutton1);
radiobutton1.setChecked(true);
```

Otherwise you can do this in xml level also.Note this line `android:checkedButton="@+id/radiobutton1"`

```
<RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checkedButton="@+id/radiobutton1"
                                                >

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radiobutton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: nope. got errors. it says that the radiobutton cannot be resolved. do i put in the onCreate? i still have errors

Answer (score 1):

You can set by `default-RadioButton` using,

By XML,

```
android:checked="true"
```

By Java,

```
radiobutton1.setChecked(true);
```

this may helps you.

Comment: if i do the java version, i get error. with xml the java doesn't know that it is checked

Answer (score 1):

Set `RadioButton`in your layout like this-

```
<RadioGroup>
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/radio_group"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="1"
         android:textSize="12dp"
         android:id="@+id/r1"
         android:checked="true"/>

    <RadioButton
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="2"
         android:id="@+id/r2"
         android:checked="false"
         android:textSize="12dp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

and in `activity` like this-

```
    RadioGrop rg= (RadioGroup)v.findViewById(R.id.radio_group);

    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
    int selectedId = radioPassanger.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

    // find the radiobutton by returned id
    RadioButton mRadioButton = (RadioButton) v.findViewById(selectedId);
```

I think it will help.